# I want to know if the equation is continuous at the point.

Tags: limits, continuity

Determine the following functions are continuous at the point $x=4.$ If they are not, give an explanation on why they are not.

a) $f(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{x},& x \geq 4 \\
        x - 2,& x < 4 
\end{cases}$

b) $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2,& x < 4 \\
         4,&  x = 4 \\
         8-x,& x > 4
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the limits of $f(x)$ at $4$

a)  $f(4) = 2$ and $\underset{x\to 4^-}{\lim} = 2$

Because they are equivalent and $f(x)$ is defined at $4$, $f(x)$ is continuous at $4$

b)  $f(4) = 4$ and $\underset{x\to 4^-}{\lim} = 16$ and $\underset{x\to 4^+}{\lim} = 4$

because they are not all equivalent $f(x)$ is not defined at $4$.